# Bash Script - using cmd instead of cat

Tags: bash, cat

I wrote a script, including this loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat "$1" | while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"; sleep 2;
done
```

A [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/) run put out the following message:

> SC2002: Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file | ..' or 'cmd file | ..' instead.

I changed the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd < "$1" | while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"; sleep 2;
done
```

but now bash exits with:

> cmd: command not found

what have I done wrong?

Comment: `cmd` is a placeholder for the thing you're **really** running. In this case, that's the `while` loop.

Comment: So, if you were running `cat foo | awk`, it would be telling you to run `awk <foo` or `awk foo` -- the `cmd` would be `awk`.

Comment: IMHO the tool is giving you bad advice here, because bash won't actually let you write `<filename while ...`; I'm not sure if `while ... done <filename` works, but for a long command it's not that readable to push the input filename all the way to the end. It's a matter of opinion, I guess, but if `cat` keeps the pipeline in order, that's a big plus point in my book.

Comment: Thank you @IMSoP I was just thinking, also for me as a beginner the `cmd < file |` makes it look like `cmd` should just replace `cat`. But that means that my first example is not _bad_ programming practise from your point of view.

Comment: A smarter tool, or a smarter shell programmer, might suggest a way to structure the whole line without the `while read`, but it's a pretty convenient idiom.

Comment: @IMSoP my first version of the script was using `for line in $(cat "$1"); do` but again, shellcheck was recommending me to use `while read -r line; do`

Comment: @nath ShellCheck suggestions can be terse but you can look at the [wiki page for SC2002](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2002) with detailed explanations and examples

Comment: @thatotherguy ok nice one, I did not know this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `cmd` is the whole `while cond; do ... done` compound statement and in this case the redirection needs to come at the end:

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"; sleep 0.2
done < "$1"
```

Comment: **nice one, thank you!** do you know what the 'cmd' stands for?

Comment: cmd can mean any command such as ps or netstat. If you wanted to process this in your loop, you would then do netstat | while read -r ....

Answer (score 3):

Remove the | and have the end line as :

```
 done < "$1"
```

Comment: `<"$1"`, rather. `<<` would be starting a heredoc.